# How to get data from two different api routes in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next.js and I need to get data from two different API routes. I want to fetch the data in `getServerSideProps`.

The first data I need is from the `http://localhost:3000/api/admin/classes/${className}` route.

The second set of data will be from `http://localhost:3000/api/admin/classes/${className}/subjects` this route.

When I try to get data from just a single API, it works fine. I tried to fetch the data from both API using the code in getServerSideProps. But it doesn't work.

I want to have the data like this `export default function classPage({ subjects, classDetail }) {}`. The return props from gerServerSideProps should look like this: `return { props: {classDetail: data, subjects: data2} }`, if it's possible

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { className } }) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/admin/classes/${className}`
  ).then(() => {
    const res2 = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/classes/${className}/subjects`)
  });
  const { data } = await res.json();
  const {data2} = await res2.json()

  return { props: { classDetail: data } };
}
```

Api get request code:

```
      try {
        const subjectDetail = await Subject.find({}).populate('classDetail')
        res.status(200).json({success: true, data: subjectDetail})
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({success: false})
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Comment: Send the first request, wait for the response and send the next request.

Comment: do I do it in the getServerSideProps, or in just any other function of my page?

Comment: You can send the requests wherever you want. If this is a question about network communication, you should minimize your code and remove React. If this is a question about React, you should elaborate. IMO, this question is too broad and needs more focus.

Comment: @jabaa I edited my description and code, can you take a look at it?

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much simpler, I assume that you don't need to wait for the first request to end to starts the second so you can simply use `Promise.all` to wait for both requests to finish.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { className } }) {
  // Create the promises for the data we need to fetch
  const promises = [
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/admin/classes/${className}`).then(res => res.json()),
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/classes/${className}/subjects`).then(res => res.json()),
  ];

  // Wait for all the promises to resolve and get the data
  const [classDetail, subjects] = (await Promise.all(promises)).map(p => p.data);

  return { props: { classDetail, subjects } };
}
```

But the problem that you seem to have with the second request is that when you write: `const {data2} = await res2.json()`, you are trying to get the attribute `data2` from the response which is probably not what you want. You need to get `data` from both responses as I did here.

Comment: I tried it out. But it shows this error: `FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/classes/class-3/subjects reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. I tried a get request in postman with the API, it shows the data just fine. Where have I gone wrong? Can you PLEASE indicate?

Comment: Are you sure that `http://localhost:3000/api/classes/${className}/subjects` gives a JSON ?

Comment: I added the api get request code in the description

Comment: What if you do `fetch(\`http://localhost:3000/api/classes/${className}/subjects\`).then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)` ?

Comment: @DjOulo I don't understand. Am I supposed to do `.then(console.log)`? If I do that it results in an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`

Comment: It was just to print what you are actually receiving in order to debug, have you solved your problem ?